# Switch/case not responding after string.split()

Tags: javascript, switch-statement

I am trying to solve a problem, where the function accepts a string, always in lowercase, and then takes the first letter and adds it to the back of the string.

It does not seem to be working.

```
var fir;

function convert(str) {
    str = str.split("");
    fir = str[0];
    str = str.join("");

switch (fir) {
  case /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/.test(fir):
    var ind = str.substr(1);
    str = ind + str[0];

    break;


}
return str;
}
```

If I call `convert("pig");` from another part of my javascript then it should return "igp"

Comment: It should return     "igp";

Comment: What is the output you are getting?

Comment: What is the behaviour you're actually trying to implement? What's the purpose of the case statement and the regex?

Comment: @Arpan I am getting "pig"

Comment: @pvg I want the first letter to be matched from the regex; then that first letter must be removed from the beginning of the string and added to the end of the string.

So i get the answer "igp".

Comment: So if the first letter matches the regex, move it to end of string otherwise leave string the same, is that it?

Comment: Essentially he is trying to look for a consonant. If he gets consonant at the beginning of the input strings he moves the first character to the end.

Comment: Because if that's the case, it's not obvious why you have a case/switch when an if will do. The split/join are also superfluous but relatively harmless.

Comment: Your switch should be for `true` and not `fir` since your case evaluates to `true` or `false`. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is all you need which does what you asked for - " function accepts a string, always in lowercase, and then takes the first letter and adds it to the back of the string".

```
function convert(str) {
    str = str.substr(1) + str[0];
        return str;
}
convert("pig");
```

If you are insistent on using what you have, I have fixed it here.

```
var fir;

function convert(str) {
    str = str.split("");
    fir = str[0];
    str = str.join("");

switch (true) {
  case /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/.test(fir):
    var ind = str.substr(1);
    str = ind + str[0];

    break;


}
return str;
}

convert("pig");
```

The only change I have done is changing `switch(fir)` to `switch(true)` which is why your switch case wasn't working.

Comment: Thanks... but any idea why my code returns  `"pig"`   and not   `"igp"` ??

Comment: Because you are using `switch(fir)` when you should be using `switch(true)` since the `case` is a condition that evaluates to `true` or `false`. I have also updated your code in my post. Please accept if you think its satisfactory.

Comment: Yes!! 

Oh thank u so much... it worked just fine :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you should read about the Javascript String Reference.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String

Remember:

> The other way (introduced in ECMAScript 5) is to treat the string as an array-like object, where individual characters correspond to a numerical index:

Now, after reading the JS String Reference. We can do something even more smart concatenating the sliced string array without the 0 index letter with the last letter of the string array.

That way you could do something without regular expressions, switch and other stuff.

Remember to always read the references about the Global Objects, it could easy save you a lot of work and get better understand of the JS Language

Example code:

```
function convert(string){
    return string.slice(1) + string[0];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your switch statement is incorrect. Your case expression `case /[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]/.test(fir)` evaluates to a boolean value while in switch expression you are passing a character in `fir` variable (as `str[0] = 'p'`) which is a mismatch. So your case statement will never get executed and it will come out of switch block without doing anything. Change it to `switch(true)` and you should be good.